# my html button with zmdi icon dont work

Tags: html, css, web

i am very bad in css/html so i ask here.

i have the this code but the button dont work :/ what i do wrong?

```
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="single-item res-sm text-center moreCards" data-uri="steam-card">
                    <div class="single-item-icon">
                        <button class="unstyled-button" style="border:none;background-color:F1F1F1;"><i href="https://steam.com" class="zmdi zmdi-steam animated infinite pulse zmdi-hc-fw"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="ht-pt">Steam</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use anchor tag instead of button?

Comment: whats a anchor tag?

Comment: <a> is an anchor tag. Use it instead of <button>

Comment: If it works please select my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51432463/6759854 . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`href` attribute does not work on `<i>` tag. It usually works on anchor tag `<a href="/some/link">Content</a>`.

Try this:

```
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="single-item res-sm text-center moreCards" data-uri="steam-card">
                <div class="single-item-icon">
                    <a href="https://steam.com" class="unstyled-button" style="border:none;background-color:F1F1F1;"><i class="zmdi zmdi-steam animated infinite pulse zmdi-hc-fw"></i></a>
                </div>
                <h4 class="ht-pt">Steam</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is mainly because you haven't added any text in between the tags
`<button>Some Text Goes Here</button>`

Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q2gtzunk/6/

If any other questions please let me know.

Comment: @LEIDERPRO please mark the answer as correct if my suggestion helped you. Thank you!